# drop duplicates dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe where I want to sum up all "Hours" (column header) into "total sum" for each "Name" (column header) under 1 "Manager" (column header). I then want to drop all duplicates before sorting the the dataframe based on the total hours sum and print out row by row. However I keep getting duplicates of the Manager row by row print out?

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      Department     |     Name         | Manager             | Hours            | 
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|   Department name   |     person Name  | Manager Name        |no of hours       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

```
def total_group(csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    df['Total Hours'] = df.groupby(['Manager'])['Hours'].transform('sum')
    new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Department', 'name', 'Manager']).sort_values('Total Hours')
    for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
        manager_value = row['Manager']
        total_hours = row['Total Hours']
        print("manager: {}, has: {} Total hours".format(manager_value, total_hours))


print(total_group(csv_file))
```

Dataframe print

```
df1 = df['Total Hours'] = df.groupby(['Direct Manager'])['Labor Hours'].transform('sum')
    print(df1)
```

result

```
0        450.0
1        450.0
2        450.0
3        450.0
4        450.0
         ...  
43929    320.5
43930    320.5
43931    320.5
43932    320.5
43933    320.5
Name: Hours, Length: 43934, dtype: float64
```

new dataframe print:

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Department', 'Direct Manager']).sort_values('Total Hours')
    print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
                     Department              Name                Hours                   Total Hours
9554             Europe                     Dri, Bas ...         8.0                        72.000000
34498           Product & Design    Sun, Sunn  ...     5.0                        81.000000
19140           Product & Design    Oers, Len  ...      8.0                        122.000000
```

what I would like is a dataframe like this:

```
                     Department              Manager                                Total Hours
9554             Europe                     Last, First ...                             72.000000
34498           Product                    Last, first  ...                         81.000000
19140           Design                     Last, First  ...                          122.000000
```

Comment: what about groupby(['Manager','Name'])['Hours']..would be helpful if you had an example df and desired output

Comment: I can post that - give me some time

Comment: Ok I have tried adding what it looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to try this

`df.groupby('Manager').agg({'Hours':['sum','count']}).sort_values(('Hours','sum'), ascending=False)`

Comment: How would it be helpful?

Comment: grouping by 'Manager' means there will no 'Manager' duplicates. 

Then you can apply the agg method with specific aggregation functions (in this case, sum and count). Then sort by the sum/Hours multi-index

`df.groupby('Manager').agg({'Hours':['sum','count']}).sort_values(('Hours','sum'), ascending=False)`

Comment: let me try it out

Comment: ```df.groupby('Manager').sum()['Hours']``` give me "nan" in total hours